# How to check if there is no data in array and show message?

Tags: angular, angular7

Now I have declaration array as:

```
public invoices: IInvoice[] = [];
```

Below it is filled by data from response:

```
 private load(): void {
    this.invoiceService.get().subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.invoices = data;
    });
  }
```

So, in template I have:

```
<div class="alert alert-fill-warning" *ngIf="invoices.length == 0"></div>
```

Problem is that while server returns data this messages is shown, because by default array is empty. How to show this message only when actually there are no data in response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the template syntax `invoice$ | async as invoices; else loading` to subscribe to an observable, but display a loading message until data is emitted. After invoices are loaded you can display the warning if the array is empty.

```
public invoices$: Observable<IInvoice[]>;

private load(): void {
   this.invoices$ = this.invoiceService.get();
}

<ng-container *ngIf="invoices$ | async as invoices; else loading">
    <div class="alert alert-fill-warning" *ngIf="invoices.length === 0"></div>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #loading">
    Invoices are loading...
</ng-template>
```

The `else loading` is optional. You can leave this area blank if you like until invoices are read.

Comment: Using Observables for this is a great way to handle this issue if you understand this technique. I would accept this as my answer.

Comment: How do we check if the `IInvoice[]` returned are empty - i.e. `length ===0`. if the initial value of `IInvoice` is `[ ]`. it will never go to `else ` and render the `loading` template. So basically we could either show the `invoices are empty` or `invoices are loading.`. I have a similar template for addresses: `*ngIf="addressService.addresses$ | async as addresses; else loading"> 
  <div class="col-12 col-md-10 py-2" *ngIf="addresses.length === 0">`

Comment: @Irshad why do you have an initial value of `[]`? You should use an observable that doesn't emit an initial value while it is fetching data. Sounds like you might be using a Redux store that has a default value. You should change the default to `null` then.

Comment: @Reactgular __ Thanks.  Ya,  I did notice that, after I commented here. Had to change the initial state to `null` rather than `[ ]`

Answer (score 2):

You could make invoices optional, and check if it is defined as well as empty

```
public invoices?: IInvoice[];

...

*ngIf="invoices && invoices.length === 0"
```

Or alternatively, use a flag, like `isFetchingData` to indicate that a fetch from the server is in progress, and use this in your `*ngIf` clause.

The flag approach is probably more obvious to the reader as to what is going on, as well as avoiding extra null checks in other parts of the code if you are using `strictNullChecking` in your tsconfig

Answer (score 1):

Is it necessary to set the default value to empty array? Why not set it to null and only change that upon receipt of data from the server. Then you can change your condition for the alert to check for non-null value that has a length of zero.

Comment: That's why I suggested changing the condition to check for *non-null* value with length of zero (i.e. `<div class="alert alert-fill-warning" *ngIf="invoices && invoices.length == 0"></div>`)

Answer (score -1):

This code will work:

```
public invoices: IInvoice[];
```

and

```
private load(): void {
this.invoiceService.get().subscribe((data: any) => {
  this.invoices = data;
});
}
```

Template's code is ok.